# add dependency an compiled maven project

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, jar, war, ear

How can I add dependency an compiled maven project?

The project structure is this:

- EAR

  --- WAR

  ----------- JAR

  ----------- JAR

  --- JAR

  --- JAR

I need add my personal JAR in the WAR project. All are maven projects.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The maven-war-plugin can perform operations like these using overlays.

Look at: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html